# Calling non-implemented static method without body

Tags: c++, templates, static, metaprogramming

```
template <class T, class U>
struct Conversion {
    typedef char Small;
    class Big
    {
        char dummy[2];
    };
    static Small Test(const U&);
    static Big Test(...);
    static T MakeT();
    enum { check=sizeof( Test( MakeT() ) ) == sizeof( Small ) };
};
```

I saw this example in the internet. It checks the conversion capability of two objects. The resource explains template tricks of old-manner cpp. I don't quite understand why MakeT() is called when passed to the Test(). And in the end why this all works. The point is there is no body in these static functions, consequently, they return nothing. Help me please.

Answer (score 4):

It is not really called because it is written inside of `sizeof` which can be applied to an unevaluated operand. `sizeof` correctly returns the size of the value returned by `Test` as `Big` is a complete type, but it does not care whether `Test` or `MakeT` has body or not.